# What's the best practice to extend a widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I want to create a custom Scaffold Widget that contains a button so that I can reuse this **CustomScaffold**. Currently, I need specify every parameters as exactly in the Scaffold's constructor as my input parameters. Is there a better way to extend a widget?

```
class CustomScaffold {
  // if I want to have fully customized Scaffold, I need to have the following (duplicate) parameters exactly the same what Scaffold defined 
  // Key key,
  // this.appBar,
  // this.body,
  // this.floatingActionButton,
  // this.floatingActionButtonLocation,
  // this.floatingActionButtonAnimator,
  // this.persistentFooterButtons,
  // this.drawer,
  // this.endDrawer,
  // this.bottomNavigationBar,
  // this.bottomSheet,
  // this.backgroundColor,
  // this.resizeToAvoidBottomPadding = true,
  // this.primary = true,

  static Scaffold createCustomScaffold({@required AppBar appBar, Widget body}) {
    final Widget cart = SafeArea(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: new Text(""),
          color: Colors.amber,
          onPressed: () {
            print("Hello");
          },
        )
      )
    );

    final Widget stack = Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          body,
          cart
        ],
     );

    return Scaffold(appBar: appBar,
                    body: stack);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

> I need specify every parameters as exactly in the Scaffold's constructor as my input parameters. Is there a better way to extend a widget?

There is no better way. There are discussions to allow more concise syntax but it's not clear this will be implemented.

Actually best practice is to not extend, but to compose, but that doesn't change that you need to forward all constructor parameters explicitly.